# How can I display an ImageField image in my template?

Tags: python, html, django

I have written the following code, the url is being fetched and is in the local host admin 127.0.0.1:8080/admin , but it is not displaying the profile picture on my website.
My code is as follows
 In models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_upload_file_name, null=True, blank=True)
    url=models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s profile' % self.user.username
```

In views.py

```
def home(request):
   context ={'request': request, 'user': request.user}
   return render(request,'home.html',context)
```

In home.html I have written the following

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block main %}
 <div>
 <h1>authentication demo</h1>
 <p>
   <ul>
   {% if user and not user.is_anonymous %}
     <li>
       <a>Hello {{ user.get_full_name|default:user.username }}!</a>
     </li>


  <img src="{{ userprofile.url }}" alt="Some alt text">
 </p>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The question is what should I add in html and how can I call the model object.

Comment: Where is `get_upload_file_name` defined, and what does it return? What is your template code?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I dont require it presently, so didnt use it. I have fetched the url and it is in the User Profile of my database. What I want it how to display profile picture using that url.

Comment: Again, please show us your _template code_.

Comment: Yes I have uploaded it

Comment: @UjjwalaPotluri. Did any of the below answers worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must `get` the `UserProfile` object like this:

```
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def home(request):
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
    context = {
        'request': request, 
        'user': request.user,
        'user_profile': user_profile,
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Then in your HTML file do this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block main %}
    <div>
        <h1>authentication demo</h1>
        <p>
            <ul> {% if user_profile and not user_profile.user.is_anonymous %}
                <li><a>Hello {{ user_profile.user.get_full_name|default:user.username }}!</a></li>
            <img src="{{ user_profile.profile_image.url }}" alt="Some alt text">
        </p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for responding. I tried your code and i am getting an error like TypeError at /

'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

Comment: Then you should show some HTML code as Chris wrote!

Comment: Seems that somewhere you are using a `for` loop to iterate over the `user`.

Comment: Hey @nik_m . Thanks for the response. This htlm tag helped me to get the ouput <img src="{{ user.profile.url }}" >. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print `{{ userprofile.url }}`, but there is no `userprofile` object in your context.

You should be able to access it via your `user` object, using the `profile` [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) you used in your profile model; make sure to also use the correct profile field (`profile_image`, not `url`), and to use the [`url` property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) of that field:

```
<img src="{{ user.profile.profile_image.url }}" alt="Some alt text">
```